# How do I keep additional traces in each subplot in Plotly in R? They all go in the top subplot

Tags: r, function, plotly

I am trying to use plotly in R and the subplot feature to plot times series of flow rates and concentrations. I have several water quality parameters and I would like to have, e.g., three subplots stacked together and in each on them have the time series of flow, and the time series of a water quality parameter of interest. For that, I have written a simple plotting function that takes both flow and concentration. When I use the code below, it looks like the first trace in each subplot (flow in my case) is correctly plotted in each subplot, but all additional traces all end up in the top subplot, as well as their secondary axis parameters... Obviously, there must be a way to use layout() to assign additional traces to the appropriate subplots. If you have any suggestion, I am interested!

Additionally, if you have suggestions to have a legend for each subplot, I am also interested. I have seen posts on that but it is still unclear how to do that for me. Thank you!

```
time <- c(1:7)
flow <- c(10,9,8,6,6,7,8.5)

NO3 <- c(5,6,6,5,4,3,4)

NH4 <- c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,1,0.9,0.8)

TSS <- c(50,45,40,43,42,41,40)

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(time,flow,NO3,NH4,TSS))


Special_plot <- function(data, parameter, rangeQ, ConcRange){ 
  
    fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~time)
  
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(type = 'scatter',
 
                                 y = ~flow,
 
                                 name = 'Flow',
 
                                 mode = 'lines',
 
                                 line = list (color = "#1f77b4"),
 
                                 showlegend = TRUE)
  
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(type = 'scatter',
                           y = ~data[,parameter],
 
                              name = parameter,
 
                              mode = 'lines' , yaxis = 'y2',
  
                                 showlegend = TRUE)
  
    fig <- fig %>% layout( yaxis = list(title = 'Flow rate', range = rangeQ),
  
                       yaxis2 = list(title = 'Concentration', 
                        range = ConcRange, overlaying = 'y', 
                        side = 'right', automargin = TRUE))

return(fig)

}

rangeQ = c(2,12)




fig1 <- Special_plot(data, "NO3",rangeQ, c(2,7)) 
fig2 <- Special_plot(data, "NH4",rangeQ, c(0,1.5))  

fig3 <- Special_plot(data, "TSS",rangeQ, c(0,50)) 


fig <- subplot(fig1,fig2,fig3,nrows = 3, shareX = TRUE)
fig
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question [at this post](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/954#issuecomment-453872899)

So, in the code above, I added another variable in the function called `Yaxis`. According to the post above, all is needed is to change in the `overlaying = "y"`, into `overlaying = Yaxis`. The variable for two subplots, the top one would have `Yaxis = 'y'`, and the second one `Yaxis = 'y3'`. For three subplots, the third subplot would have `Yaxis = 'y5'`. The list goes on and on with for every extra subplot the `Yaxis` wouls take `y7`, `y9`, etc. I do not understand why it works and I cannot find [in this ebook](https://plotly-r.com/)

so the code that seems to work is:

```html
time <- c(1:7)
flow <- c(10,9,8,6,6,7,8.5)

NO3 <- c(5,6,6,5,4,3,4)

NH4 <- c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,1,0.9,0.8)

TSS <- c(50,45,40,43,42,41,40)

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(time,flow,NO3,NH4,TSS))


Special_plot <- function(data, parameter, rangeQ, ConcRange, Yaxis){ 
  
  fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~time)
  
  fig <- fig %>% add_trace(type = 'scatter',
                           
                           y = ~flow,
                           
                           name = 'Flow',
                           
                           mode = 'lines',
                           
                           line = list (color = "#1f77b4"),
                           
                           showlegend = TRUE)
  
  fig <- fig %>% add_trace(type = 'scatter',
                           y = ~data[,parameter],
                           
                           name = parameter,
                           
                           mode = 'lines' , yaxis = 'y2',
                           
                           showlegend = TRUE)
  
  fig <- fig %>% layout( yaxis = list(title = 'Flow rate', range = rangeQ),
                         
                         yaxis2 = list(title = 'Concentration', 
                                       range = ConcRange, overlaying = Yaxis, 
                                       side = 'right', automargin = TRUE))
  
  return(fig)
  
}

rangeQ = c(2,12)




fig1 <- Special_plot(data, "NO3",rangeQ, c(2,7),'y') 
fig2 <- Special_plot(data, "NH4",rangeQ, c(0,1.5),'y3')  

fig3 <- Special_plot(data, "TSS",rangeQ, c(0,50),'y5') 


fig <- subplot(fig1,fig2,fig3,nrows = 3, shareX = TRUE)
fig
```

I still have not solved the legend issue though.